# Measurement and dimension is off

Tags: measurement, dimensions

My object measures 300 mm high but in the dimensions it is registering at 151mm. how  do I make them matchup? why are they different?

Comment: Please add screenshots. Especially the sidebar. There can be a few different reasons as to why your model is doing that.

Comment: (Please don't use all caps .. it's considered shouting, here) Maybe even share on https://blend-exchange.com/